# Perl using regex to compare fields with multiple delimiters

Tags: perl

I am studying Perl.
My data.txt file contains:

```
Lori:James Apple
Jamie:Eric Orange
```

My code below prints the first line "Lori:James Apple"

```
open(FILE,'data.txt');
while(<FILE>){
  print if /James/;
}
```

But how do I modify my regular expression to search for a specific field?
For example, I'd like to use 2 delimiters ' ' and ':' to make each line contain 3 fields and check if the 3rd field of the first line is Apple. Which will be equivalent to `awk -F'[ :]' '$3 = "Lori"' data.txt`

Answer (score 4):

One simple way with regex is to use the [negated character class](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Bracketed-Character-Classes) (also see it [in perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-character-classes))

```
open my $fh, '<', $file  or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (my $line = <$fh>) 
{
    my @fields = $line =~ /([^:\s]+)/g;
}
```

The `[^...]` matches any character other than those listed inside (after `^` which "negates"). The `+` [quantifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) means to match one-or-more times so the whole pattern matches a string of consecutive characters other than `:` and "white space." See docs for a precise description of `\s`. If you actually mean to skip only a single literal space use `[^: ]`. All this is *captured* by `()`.

The search keeps going through the string due to the *global modifier* `/g`, finding all such matches. Since it is in the *list [context](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context)* it returns the list of matches, which is assigned to `@fields` array.

One can pick elements "on the fly" by indexing into the list, `($line =~ /([^:\s]+)/g)[2]`. If we are matching `$_` this is `(/([^:\s]+)/g)[2]`.

I suggest a good read through [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), for starters.

---

On the other hand, it is often simpler and clearer to use [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)

```
my @fields = split /[:\s]/, $line;
```

This also uses regex for the pattern by which to split the string. The character class is not negated since here it specifies the delimiter itself, either `:` or `\s` (each delimiter may be either of these, they don't have to all be the same).

---

I would now like to answer the specific question, but the question isn't clear to me.

It asks to "*check if the 3rd field of the first line is Apple*", what can be done for example by

```
while (<$fh>) 
{
    if ( (/([^:\s]+)/g)[2] eq 'Apple' ) {
        # ....
    }
}
```

but it isn't clear what to do with it. Perhaps get the first field by what the third one is?

I suggest to get an array and then process. One can write a regex to identify and pick fields directly but that's more brittle and the regex itself then depends on the position (and number) of fields.

At this point we are in a guessing game. If you need more detail please clarify.

The given `awk` code would yield `Lori James Lori` and I don't see how that fits.

Comment: For the specific question of "how to modify the regex" I suppose the answer could be something like `/^([^: ]*[: ]){2}James($|[ :])/`

Comment: @tripleee  Yes, but I don't see what the specific question is (the offered examples are conflicting). I did add another section on it ... but I feel that I'm in a guessing game at this point.  (Btw, that needs to be `{1}` I think? Or `Apple` instead of `James`.)

Comment: `{1}` is pointless; if something isn't repeated, you simply don't specify a number of repetitions (or otherwise we would say `/J{1}a{1}m{1}e{1}s{1}/`).  I'm skipping the first two fields and the following delimiter so that's why it's two repetitions.  But yeah, probably look for `Apple` in the third field, or target the second field instead.

Comment: @tripleee Agree, that in my comment was a parenthetical remark on the actual code in your comment (just meant to note that it doesn't match as it stands, in case somebody copies it blindly).  It is a good way to parse by fields, of course.  (Btw, I would _not_ recommend that to a beginning study. Btw, honestly, I personally don't go for those in a complex production code either.)  I would gladly offer an interesting regex as a side answer, but I actually don't see what the precise question is.  I understood that there isn't one, they are asking how to do it in general.

Comment: @tripleee  Thank you for the comments!  It's always good to see you around :)

Comment: @tripleee (You may not remember, but you helped me out a _lot_ by good advice when I started posting, around a year ago :)

Comment: Oh, hi, good to see you have gained a significant amount of rep!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is - don't. Regular expressions are about pattern matching, and not context.

You *can* define a pattern that builds in delimiters and fields, but ... it's not the right tool for the job.

The answer is use `split` and then handle the fields separately.

```
open ( my $input, '<', 'data.txt' ) or die $!; 
while(<$input>){
    chomp;
    my @fields = split /[\s:]/;
    print if $fields[2] eq "Apple";
}
```

You can compact this further if you wish, but I'd advise caution - compressing your code at the expense of readability isn't a virtue.

Also - whilst we're at it:

```
open(FILE,'data.txt');
```

is bad style - it doesn't check for success, and it also uses a global file handle name. It would be much better to:

```
open ( my $input, '<', 'data.txt' ) or die $!;
```

The `autodie` pragma also does this implicitly.